# Angular frontend, then C# Backend with Syntax errors: HTTP Controller receiving a JSON object in the body

Tags: c#, json, angular, http-post, frombodyattribute

Trying to get a basic model of my functions working.

Frontend (Angular): the body data will be JSON of this class:

```
class BackendParams {
  listValues: any;

  constructor( netList: any ) {
    this.listValues = netList;
  }
}
```

Then a function creates the class object:

```
const params = new BackendParams(list);
```

then calls a (still in the front-end) Angular function to send it to the backend:

```
  onClickTest(params: any) {
    const A = 1;
    const B = 2;
    const NameString = 'test';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('NetworkList', JSON.stringify(params));
    let url = `${this.url}/CalibrationModel/1/2/SampleTest/TestModel`;

    this.http.post(url, formData).subscribe(  
          (data) => { 
            console.log(data);
          });
  }
```

BACKEND:

```
class BackendParams
{
    List<Constituent> listNetworkConstituents;

}
```

The following is image of the source code so you can see the syntax red underlines
[image: Note 2 syntax errors]

I don't think the two are related (or are they?) but referencing the body parameters is of course essential.

And, of course, let me know anything else you see that might be a problem.

Thanks for your help.  I learn a lot from you guys.
Yogi

Comment: These look like type conversion errors to me - your return type is Task<> but you are trying to return a boolean. You only need to use Task with an async method so there's no need for it here. Change the return type to boolean to fix that one.

Comment: Hi John,  I'm still confused.  The code above says Task<bool>, right so shouldn't that mean the return of a bool 'x' should work?  OR are you saying I'm not returning a TASK of boolean type?

Comment: You aren't returning a Task of boolean type, but there is no need for it anyways because you aren't calling anything asynchronously.
Tbh I'm not really sure why that boolean is even there - it's just set to true and returned no matter what happens in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method were marked as `async` then returning a `bool` would work. So `public async Task<bool>...`, but that isn't the case. However, as @JohnD91 said, if you're not using `await` in your method, it doesn't need to be `async` and it also doesn't need to return a `Task`.

The other problem is that `parmsJSON` is misspelled, because it's defined in the method signature as `paramsJSON`. You're missing the other `a`.

Comment: Hi Matt.  I'm glad the whole thing wasn't just a mispelling... LOL thanks.
Now for the async.  If I understand correctly, I must have 'async' in order to return a value... and I see now (having tried this) you are absolutely correct. 
I'm marking your answer correct, but if you care to comment further, is there a way to pass a return type FROM a Task without marking async, since async insists that the function contain an await-able internal function.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can `return Task.FromResult(x)`. But then the type returned from the method is not simply `bool` , it's `Task<bool>`.